# Ways to achieve N with some given integers

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation

This Question has been asked in facebook's test :
Suppose there's a game in which we score either 2, 3 or 7 in each turn. In how many ways can we achieve a score of X?

Comment: This isn't a programming question; flagging as off-topic.

Comment: This has been asked in fb's on-campus test!

Comment: It also has nothing to do with coding style. *Please* read the descriptions for tags before you use them.

Comment: Are you familiar with dynamic programming?

Comment: An answer to a question that was asked wouldn't help as much as reading about basics would.  Go back to school.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming. Try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Barmar This is probably off-topic because it is a lazy question.  It __is__ about programming.

Comment: This problem is indeed a programming problem, but @user1611542 you should at least show something to prove that you've done some thinking :)

Comment: If you are preparing for facebook's test, prepare by solving such problems yourself or by visiting school topics as suggested by @Oxdeadbeef. If this problem came in your test, share your code or algo or anything which you did related to this question during the test.

Comment: @user1611542 still needs help?

Comment: I have figured O(n^2) and O(n) solution, but I was looking for constant order solution (which is possible for small coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a very typical knapsack problem, or more specific, a coin-change problem.

We have several ways to solve this kind of problem, but we could solve it using **Dynamic Programming** easily.

This [page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/) explained the solution quite well, please digest it on your own pace :)

For a quick look, here is a pseudo code about the problem:

```
int coins[3] = {2, 3, 7};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)  
    for (int j = coins[i]; j <= X; ++j)  
        dp[j] += dp[j - coins[i]];
```

You can also try [this](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=615), a very similar problem on Uva.